# IP from MAC Address of a computer not in my network(remote)

Tags: ip-address, remote-access, mac-address, tightvnc

I do not know if this is even a valid question but I am trying to get the IP address of a computer that I try to remotely connect to via TightVNC.

I have checked some answers on the SO, but they were mostly about the ARP-table for finding the ip-mac on the current network, not on a remote computer.

Unfortunately I only took note of local IP and MAC address of the remote computer when leaving it, but right after going to holidays, I realized I do not know the actual global IP. Now I am wondering whether there is a way to know the IP via a running PC with a specific IP.

Maybe related to this question, I was wondering if there is anyway that I can check the recent IP's with my current Windows computer which it has used, so I would know the IP range of the network that I used in the previous days and use that to find my remote PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a DDNS server, like http://www.noip.com/ where you install a software in your remote PC, and will update the IP in the no-ip server, now you will be able to connect to that remote PC, using a name like   remote_pc_from_A.Yazdiha.no-ip.org in your ThigthVNC client.

Comment: The problem is that I currently have no access to the remote pc, it is just on with internet, so I cannot install any software on it.

Comment: A lot of these DDNS solutions are also supported in many routers. Then there is no need to install software on the pc.

Answer (score 0):

This Batch Code will fetch the below Details,

1. PC Name
2. IP Address
3. MAC Address
4. Computer Description(If Available)

Please save the below code in **anyname.bat** format and run it. It will output the results in a separate text file.

```
    :: This Windows Batch(CMD) File fetches All the Details of the Nearby PC's of Same VLAN (Upto 254 host's).
    :: Windows OS (CMD)
    :: Author : [M.S.Arun][1]

    :: #****************************************************************** Start of Script ********************************************************************#

    @echo off
    title Remote PC Details Fetching Script(PC Name / IP's / Computer Description)
    echo. > %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt
    echo Remote PC Details Fetching Script (PC Name / IP's / Computer Description) details of the Nearby PC's of Same VLAN.(Upto 254 Hosts)
    echo.
    set /p input_ip="Please Enter the IP Range(Eg:192.168.1) :  " && echo
    set /p input_ip_start="Please Enter Start IP Range(Eg:1) :  " && echo
    set /p input_ip_end="Please Enter End IP Range(Eg:254) :  " && echo
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt
    @echo on
    for /l %%i in (%input_ip_start%, 1, %input_ip_end%) do nbtstat -a %input_ip%.%%i | findstr /c:"MAC" /c:"<00>" | findstr /c:"MAC" /c:"UNIQUE" >> %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt && echo     IP Address  = %input_ip%.%%i >> %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt
    @echo off
    echo. > %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. > %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo This Batch Script fetches All the Details of the Nearby PC's of Same VLAN.(Starting from 1 to 254 host's) >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo PC Host Name: >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    find "UNIQUE" PC_Details_Temp.txt >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo PC IP Address: >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    find "IP" PC_Details_Temp.txt >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo PC MAC Address: >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    find "MAC" PC_Details_Temp.txt >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo PC Seat No's. and Vnet No's: >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    net view /all >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    arp -a >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    :: del %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt
    echo.
    echo Completed Successfully..!
    echo.
    pause

    :: #****************************************************************** End of Script ********************************************************************#
```

Hope this might help.

Screenshots For References,
[image]

[image]